# Dynamically draw rectangle between the Dragable objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

My aim is to highlight the area between the two dragable objects `inpoint_mc` and `scrub_outpoint_mc`, so i had created a rectangle between these points, i need to resize this rectangle based on the dragpoints, which indicates the distance between Inpoint and Outpoint, i tried my level best unfortunately i can acheive it

```
private function startScrubbingIN(_arg1:MouseEvent){
        trace("scrubBarIsMovingIN");
        this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, this.stopScrubbingIN);
        this.cueCard.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, this.scrubBarIsMovingIN);
        this.scrubbing = true;
       var _local2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.y, 
            this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.x-this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, 0);
        // now we're limiting in point to current position of out point
        this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.startDrag(false, _local2);

        this.controls_mc.addChild(_seekIndicator);
        _seekIndicator.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
        _seekIndicator.graphics.drawRect(this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.x, this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.y, 
            this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.x-this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x, 12);
        trace("_seekIndicator"+ _seekIndicator);
            // _seekIndicator.width = this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.x+ this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.y;
      }
```

it giving me the result as like the attached image

[image]

but the red rectangle need to be shrink itself between the 2 Points

Comment: I'd suggest drawing 1 pixel wide indicator and scaling it instead of redrawing as follows http://wonderfl.net/c/qQHG

Comment: @www0z0k appreciate your comment :)

Comment: @www0z0k, i tried to add you snippet with my Stage video player, it having some wired behaviors

Comment: @www0z0k i beleive `RELEASE_OUTSIDE` is not in the AS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rectangle should be redrawn only after you stop dragging, or when you move mouse while dragging. Don't forget to call `_seekIndicator.graphics.clear()` to delete old rectangle. And finally, use `this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.x` and `this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.x` for borders, because you're saying the rectangle should be between the in and out point MCs, while you use `this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.x` in width.

```
private function scrubBarIsMovingIN(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // the startDrag dragged one of the sliders already
    // existing code skipped, if any
    _seekIndicator.graphics.clear();
    _seekIndicator.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
    _seekIndicator.graphics.drawRect(this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.x, this.controls_mc.progressBar_mc.y, 
        this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.x-this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.x, 12);
}
```

Should do.

Comment: Thanks man, its' working like charm :). Thanks again for the excellent answer

Comment: Hello @Vesper, am getting some issues on this answer on Fullscreen mode, the rectangles are not resizing, remain all my controls are looks good.

Comment: @JothiKannan You should check your display list, `_seekIndicator` should be a child of `controls_mc`.

Comment: Yes @Vesper it's a child `this.controls_mc.addChild(_seekIndicator);`. but am not sure why its not resized on fullscreen

Comment: If so, check if effective coordinates `this.controls_mc.inpoint_mc.x`  and `this.controls_mc.scrub_outpoint_mc.x` change after performing fullscreen, and if yes, just call `scrubBarIsMovingIN(null)`. If not, then please ask another question, specifying as many details as you can.

Comment: could you please explain more on the above comment ? i can't get your point exactly

Comment: posted as new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520475/seekbar-posistion-is-not-rearranging-on-fullscreen-mode-in-as3 , please check it

Comment: have any idea on this ? am struglling with Fullscreen controls @Vesper